# Simple restful webservice example with multiple @get and @put

Tags: web-services, http, rest, get

Dear Stackoverflow user,
Could anyone give me an simple example of restful webservice with 2 or more @get and @put in netbeans? Any simple plain text example is sufficient. And it should not include any database!
I would be very glad if some one could help me.
I tried something but it didn't work out, here's the code

```
@Path("/simple")
public class SimpleResource_1 {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        return "hello world";
    }
@Path("/simple/simple1")
public class SimpleResource_11 {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getText1(){
    return "hi";
}
}
```

I get runtime error with this code, though there aren't any compilation error.
Am i doing it right? or is there something i am missing!!

Thanx a ton in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester i use javax.ws, thank for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default Netbeans server stack and are thus using `javax.ws.rs`:

```
@Path("/admin/")
public class AdminResource {

    @GET
    @Produces('text/plain')
    @Path("/reset/")
    public String reset() {
        return "Reset successfully";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces('text/plain')
    @Path("/close/")
    public String closeAll() {
        return "Closed Successfully";
    }
}
```

You should only have one public class per Java file. Netbeans should sort out the required imports for the code above if you have created a standard web service project. If you wanted to add a `@PUT` you just add another method to the resource and annotate it appropriately.

Comment: thank you very much for replying, but when i add this code in my netbeans, i get an error "annotation type not applicable for this kind of application"

Comment: Any help would be very much appreciated?

Comment: Thanks mate, i figured it out, the problem was with the second get in the line produce. thanks you very much mate. But how will implement put? is it similar to get?